# What is the issue with this CGI/HTML/Perl program?

Tags: html, perl, xampp, cgi

I am using XAMMP Apache Server. There is a text file named 'animal.txt' containing the name of an animal on each line, with a basic description.

I am trying to write a Perl program, using HTML and CGI. The aim of the program is to have the user search an animal name, using a HTML form. This will then link to a Perl program which loops through the animal.txt file and reads the file line by line. The program will take any line that matches the users search from the original HTML form, and print all animals containing the same name.

So far this is where I am :

(Clientside form)

```
#!\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe
use CGI qw/:standard/; # load standard CGI routines
use CGI::Carp('fatalsToBrowser'); 

print header(); # create the HTTP header
print  <<HTML
<head>
  <title>Shop Here</title>
 </head>
 <body>

<h1>Animal list search</h1>

     A basic form  <br />

  <form action="dumpsVar2.pl"> 
    Search:     <input type="text", name="Search" size=5><br><br>
    Submit:     <input type="submit" name="select" size="7"><br>
    </form> 
  </body>
 </html>
 HTML
```

And then the perl program:  (Server-Side)
       #!\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp('fatalsToBrowser'); 
$query = new CGI;

@parameters = $query -> param;
print header, start_html("Parameters");
print "$0 was passed these parameters:<br>  <br> ";

foreach $name (@parameters) {
    $value = $query -> param($name);
    print p("$name = $value"); 
} 
$inFile = "animal.txt";
open (IN, $inFile) or die "Can't find file: $inFile";

@animals = (<IN>);
$item = param;
foreach $line (<IN>) {
    if ($line =~ /$item/) {
        print "$item";
    }
}

print end_html;
```

Comment: That's nice and all... but what's your question?

Comment: What does your perl executable have to do with anything?

Comment: yes sorry. The program will not print any animals from the text file that contain the name the user searches for, how do I solve this?

Comment: See how much easier your code is to read when you use indentation?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here - I'd appreciate it if anyone can help

Answer (score 1):

Several issues here, but the crux of the matter is this code.

```
@animals = (<IN>);
$item = param;
foreach $line (<IN>) {
    if ($line =~ /$item/) {
        print "$item";
    }
}
```

Let's look at each line in turn:

```
@animals = (<IN>);
```

This reads all of the data from `IN` into the array `@animals`. It also leaves `IN`'s file pointer at the end of the file. Any further attempts to read data from `IN` will fail.

```
$item = param;
```

If you call `param` with no arguments, you get a list of the parameter names that were found in the CGI request. As you're assigning this list to a scalar value, this behaviour changes and you'll get the *number* of parameters. In your system this will always be 1.  So `$item` contains the value 1.

```
foreach $line (<IN>) {
```

Remember how you read all of the data from `IN` a couple of lines back? Well you're trying to read more data from it here. And that's not going to work. I think you probably wanted `@animals` here, not `<IN>`. Currently your `foreach` is never executed as on the first iteration the call to `<IN>` returns `undef` - which is false.

```
if ($line =~ /$item/) {
```

Let's assume that you've replaced `<IN>` with `@animals` in your `foreach` loop - so that the loop body is actually executed. This still isn't doing what you wanted. Remember that `$item` contains 1 rather than the name of an animal to search for. And I doubt that you have an animal called "1".

What you probably want is something more like this:

```
my $animal = param('Search');
while (<IN>) {
    print if /$animal/;
}
```

I'd also point out that learning CGI in 2014 is pretty ridiculous. You would be far better off looking at a simple Perl web framework like Web::Simple or Dancer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is

```
$item = param;
```

Which is putting the number of parameters in your form, in this case 2, into $item. I doubt you have an animal named 2

Change it to

```
$item = param('Search');
```